# Post request with react redux toolkit

Tags: redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I have recently switched from redux to redux toolkit. I understand basic state management but I dont know how to make an (axios) post request to my backend with the state data as a payload.

Comment: You can read a complete explanation with example in Redux official tutorials : https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic. Take time to read from, at least Part 3 which describes the structure of the example app, including a file named client.js that contains the logic for sending GET or POST request using Ajax such as Axios. In the example, it uses Fetch API, from which you can replace it with Axios.

Comment: Actually there is a new elegant way for data fetching and caching, i.e using Redux Toolkit (RTK) Query which is covered in part 7 and 8 of the tutorials, but it internally uses Fetch API. I am still figuring out how to use Axios with RTK Query.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a slice like this:

```
import {createSlice, } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const initialState = {
  todos: [],
  loading: false,
  errorMessage: null,
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loadTodos(state) {
      state.loading = true;
      state.errorMessage = null;
    },
    loadTodosError(state, action) {
      state.loading = false;
      state.errorMessage = action.payload.message;
    },
    loadTodosSuccess(state, action) {
      state.loading = false;
      state.errorMessage = null;
      state.todos = action.payload.data
    },
  },
});

export const {actions, reducer} = slice;
```

and given that redux toolkit comes with a 'special' function called 'createAsyncThunk' that is usually used with async actions, you can call it like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const loadTodos = createAsyncThunk(
  'loadTodos',
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://todos.com/api', 'delete');
    thunkAPI.dispatch(actions.loadTodosSuccess(response.data));
    return response;
  });
```

then all you have to do is to import the actions and dispatch them like this

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {loadTodos} from './slice';

const TodoList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadTodos());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const {isLoading, errorMessage} = useSelector(state => state.todos);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading && <Spinner />}
      {errorMessage && <span>Failed to load todos</span>}
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <div>{todo}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```